# Remove the white spaces after the splitting the file in to list

Tags: python, list

```
for line_1 in file_1 :
    split_op_1 = line_1.split(',')
    print(split_op_1)
```

Input : `547727, 547728, 553876, 557264,`

Output: `'547727', ' 547728', ' 553876', ' 557264',`

Required Output: `'547727', '547728', '553876', '557264',`

How do I remove the extra space from the beginning of each list element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
split_op_1 = [i.strip() for i in split_op_1.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for line_1 in file_1 :
    split_op_1 = line_1.split(',')
    print(list(map(str.strip, split_op_1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strip()` function removes leading and trailing whitespaces when applied to a string:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods